# Invoking AWS Lambda endpoint

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I implemented AWS lambda method to learn what I can do with it.
What I have now:

- AWS lambda itself
- API Gateway
- Amazon CloudWatch Logs

In API Gateway configs I see next options:

- Endpoint: *https://xyz.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dummy/test-store*
- API key: *QW123E45RTY6*
- Authorization: *NONE*

Behind this lambda I have Java code, implementing *com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestStreamHandler* and a REST controller behind it, something like that:

```
@Path("/tester")
public class TestResource {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());

    private TestRepository testRepository;

    public void setTestRepository(TestRepository testRepository) {
        this.testRepository = testRepository;
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/{identifier}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Consumes(MediaType.WILDCARD)
    public Response store(@PathParam("identifier") String identifier, @QueryParam("hashcode") String hashcode) {
        try {
            this.testRepository.store(identifier, hashcode);
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            LOG.error("Failed to store pair {}, {}", identifier, hashcode, ex);
            throw new InternalServerErrorException(ex);
        }
        return Response.noContent().build();
    }
}
```

Now I tried invoking this service through Postman:

**Option 1** - Invoke what I saw in API Gateway:

- URL: *https://xyz.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dummy/test-store*
- Method: POST
- Headers:

  - Key: x-api-key
  - Value: QW123E45RTY6

Result: 404 Not Found, see the appropriate logs in AWS CloudWatch.

**Option 2** - Invoke my method:

- URL: *https://xyz.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dummy/test-store/tester/qwerty123*
- Method: POST
- Headers:

  - Key: x-api-key
  - Value: QW123E45RTY6

Result: 403 Forbidden, no logs in AWS CloudWatch.

```
{
    "message": "Missing Authentication Token"
}
```

I fully understand why **Option 1** did not work, but what went wrong with **Option 2**? Could you please help me understanding what I missed?

Answer (score 2):

This message occurs (most of the times) when you try to call URL that doesn't exist.

Please make sure you are calling `http://api-gateway-name/stage-name/resource-name`

Also, make sure you have deployed your API.

Comment: Thank you for your hint, you was right that URL was wrong, but I did not understand why it was wrong before I dived into the AWS client's code. I'm going to paste my finding as a separate answer here.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my problem was simple and obvious (silly me). Endpoint configuration in API gateway **must** match the `@Path` configurations in Java code.

So if I define `dummmy/test-store` in gateway, should use `@Path("/dummmy/test-store")` instead of `@Path("/tester")`.

Addressed this limitation and made my `Lambda`-based API lightweight by implementing the handler manually, without overhead of regular REST API frameworks. Even published my WIP "framework" on [GitHub](https://github.com/stepio/lambda-lite).